# fwrite no escribe a archivo

Tags: c, archivo

tengo este programa hex_editor.exe en c que lee de un archivo de texto con este formato:

```
065_066_067_097_098_099_013_010_049_050_051
052_053_054_013_010_065_114_114_111_122_032
121_032_108_101_099_104_101_013_010_100_111
013_010_013_010_119_104_105_108_101_
```

y luego crea un nuevo archivo escribiendo los números del archivo de texto a otro archivo byte por byte

el código es este:

```
int main (int argc,char **argv)
{
    from_hex_file(argv[1],argv[2]);
}

void from_hex_file(char name[],char new_name[])
{
    FILE* hex_file,* new_file;
    unsigned char num;
    char str[4];

    hex_file=fopen(name,"r");
    new_file=fopen(new_name,"wb");
    if(hex_file==NULL||new_file==NULL)
    {
       if(hex_file==NULL)
          printf("error no se pudo abrir el archivo\n");
       if(new_file==NULL)
          printf("error no se pudo crear el archivo\n");
       system("pause");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        while(EOF!=fscanf(hex_file,"%3[^\n_]%c*",str))
        {
            num=(int)strtol(str,(char **)NULL,10);
            fwrite(&num,sizeof(num),1,new_file);
        }
    }
fclose(new_file);
fclose(hex_file);
```

}

mi problema es que cuando corro el programa en cmd con:

```
hex_editor prueba.txt res.txt
```

no me escribe nada  a res.txt ,ya me asegure de que fwrite este escrbiendo por que comprobe si retornaba 1 ,se que el problema tiene que ver algo con el buffer o fflush pero no consigue saber que es

Comment: Proba con la variable str darle un tamaño de 4.

Comment: sigue dejando res.txt vacio

Comment: Mmmmm, raro a mi con esto me funcionó, si usas linux, talves sea un problema de privilegios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La fuente del problema no es el `fwrite()`, sino el `scanf()` previo, que no lee correctamente el patrón que esperas en el fichero.

Para empezar parece tener un error tipográfico, pues la expresión que has puesto:

```
%3[^\n_]%c*
```

no es sintácticamente correcta, y el compilador se queja de que este `fscanf()` especifica dos parámetros en su cadena de formato (el `%3...` y el `%c`), pero luego sólo recibe una variable parámetro para dejarlo. Sospecho que querías decir `%*c` en lugar de `%c*`. Tal como está, da un *segfault* al ejecutarse.

De cualquier forma, aún corrigiendo el error antes dicho, el programa no funciona correctamente ya que una vez llega al último número, sigue leyéndolo una y otra vez sin detectar el EOF, en un bucle infinito, y no alcanzo a comprender muy bien el por qué. Creo que es debido a que la última línea del fichero tiene tanto un `_` como un `\n` tras el número de tres cifras, pero tu expresión lee sólo hasta el `_` y el `\n` queda sin leer, una y otra vez.

El problema sin embargo se soluciona si simplificas la cadena de formato de `fscanf()`. A fin de cuentas ¿por qué especificarle que debe haber tres caracteres distintos de `\n` y `_` seguidos? Basta decirle que lea tres caracteres, sin más, y que ignore el siguiente grupo de caracteres mientras sean `\n` o `_`. Así:

```
while(EOF!=fscanf(hex_file,"%3c%*[\n_]",str))
```

Con ese cambio el programa ejecuta sin problemas y la salida es la deseada.